# Can I create a post in a Google+ Community direct from Gmail?

Tags: email, google-plus, google-plus-communities

In migrating an organisation from Yahoo Groups to a Google+ Community, we're finding that one of the features that users miss the most is the ability to start a new thread from an email sent to a group address. Is there a way to do this in Google+ Communities that we've not discovered yet?

Answer (score -1):

In short, yes you can; I recently followed a group on Google+, and every day after I was getting an email or two, from a group member, who was simply sharing something socially as they went about their day.

Suffice it to say, that I know have group messages turned off. You can read more about it, get details of how to do it here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/umichcollab/4dCDeJrl2xA

and here:
https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/going-google/tech-updates/emailgoogleconnections

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. He/she wants a way to _start_ a Google+ thread by sending an email, while you are talking about receiving email notifications when something happens on Google+.

Comment: i can read, and that functionality, comes pre-baked, with google sites.

Comment: But the links you post both just mention how to _email someone from Google+_, not how to _start a thread on Google+ by sending an email_. If that is possible with Google Sites, could you add the necessary steps for how to do it to your answer?

Comment: you can message anyone, anywhere, anytime, anyplace, as long as there is a + button to do it with. ergo, from gmail (IN YOUR EMAIL) you can send a message to your group. they are one in the same. even without searching through documentation/specs, this has been on the board, plain as day, forever. every google product will integrate and become +. and if you want to be uber semantic about it, OP did not ask how, they asked IF, twice. so, thanks for thinking for the postee and the respondee. we can leave and you can play both roles :)

Comment: A [Google+ Community](http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/communities/) is not the same as a [Google Group](https://groups.google.com). The OP specifically wants to _start a new thread on his Google+ **Community** by sending an email_, so that (my interpretation) _the post shows up on his Google+ Community page_.

Comment: Thanks, Vidar, that's correct. Google+ Groups and Communities work differently in this regard. Although there doesn't seem to be any good reason for it.

Thanks for your input, Albert.