# How to use email to send a post to Google+ Community

Tags: google-plus-communities

My team uses a private Google+ Community for updates. If I need to call in sick, I would have to navigate to the Community and post. The last time I tried, it continuously failed on my Galaxy S3, though my Gmail worked fine.

Is there a way to send an email to the Community and my message be added as a post?

Note: I did read this post ([Can I create a post in a Google+ Community direct from Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57472/can-i-create-a-post-in-a-google-community-direct-from-gmail)), and the answer was not determined and seems that the post was abandoned as an argument was beginning. To clarify, I want to know "how to use email to send a post to Google + Community."

I am fairly certain this is possible as I am able to respond to other members' posts directly from my inbox.